# How to disable certificate checking in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using [Symfony/Doctrine](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) and I wish to disable the certificate checking when my app wishes to connect with my server (the server only has auto signed certificate).

I have tried to do this in `doctrine.php` configuration file:

```
$container->setParameter('env(DATABASE_URL)', $ulrDb);

$container->loadFromExtension('doctrine', [
        'dbal' =>
            [
                'port' =>  $port,
                'driver' => $driver,
                'user' => $username,
                'password' =>  $password,
                'host' => $hostname,
                'dbname' => $name,
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'default_table_options' =>
                    [
                        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                        'collate' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                    ],
                'options' =>
                    [
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
                    ]
            ],
        'orm' => [
            'auto_generate_proxy_classes' => '%kernel.debug%',
            'naming_strategy' => 'doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore',
            'auto_mapping' => true,
            'mappings' => [
                'App' => [
                    'is_bundle' => false,
                    'type' => 'annotation',
                    'dir' => '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity',
                    'prefix' => 'App\Entity',
                    'alias' => 'App'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

These are the errors:

```
> bin/console make:migration 

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.  


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.  


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.  


make:migration [--db DB] [--em [EM]] [--shard SHARD] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Is it possible to enable the checking certificate from the php.ini? And in which way? Or are there others ways?

Comment: Do you have access to the mysql server, if yes set `require_secure_transport` to ÒFF` in the mysql configuration

Answer (score 0):

On your mysql server set `require_secure_transport` to `OFF` in the mysql configuration ;)